# Why is this ARM binary throwing an 'Illegal instruction' error and quitting?

Tags: arm

## Issue

I'm hoping someone can help me determine why this binary won't execute.

It is a closed-source, stripped ARM binary. That said, it is freely downloadable on the internet so there is a link to it at the bottom of this post.

The target is an ARM binary pulled from a firmware image. I have set up an ARM VM, but have also tried running the binary on a Pi with the same result.

Here is what I'm seeing:

```
root@debian-armel:/tmp/squashfs-root/usr/bin# ./my_arm_bin 
Illegal instruction
```

That "Illegal instruction" error is not super helpful... so I dug in a little deeper.

## My VM

I don't think the problem is my VM. It is a pretty standard ARM VM setup. From: https://people.debian.org/~aurel32/qemu/armel/

Using `debian_squeeze_armel_standard.qcow2`, `initrd.img-2.6.32-5-versatile`, and `vmlinuz-2.6.32-5-versatile`. It is launched with QEMU with a few ports forwarded (ssh,http,31337 for gdb stuff). I am able to execute other ARM binaries on the system without issue, including other binaries pulled from the same firmware image.

Also, as mentioned before I've tried dropping the binary onto a Pi with no luck. I tried both as root on the pi, as well as in a chroot'ed environment with the rootfs of the extracted firmware image, same result: `Illegal Instruction`.

## r2 Info

`rabin2 -I my_arm_bin`:

```
Warning: Cannot initialize dynamic strings
arch     arm
binsz    44831825
bintype  elf
bits     32
canary   false
class    ELF32
crypto   false
endian   little
havecode true
lang     c
linenum  false
lsyms    false
machine  ARM
maxopsz  16
minopsz  1
nx       false
os       linux
pcalign  0
pic      false
relocs   false
rpath    NONE
static   true
stripped true
subsys   linux
va       true
```

## Additional Debugging (gdb w/ gef on Pi)

So, time to attach a debugger and see exactly what instruction is actually throwing that error. This was done on a Pi.

After starting up and breaking on entry, using `ni` to single step, I see:

```
gef> x/20i $pc
=> 0x796a0: mov r11, #0
   0x796a4: mov lr, #0
   0x796a8: pop {r1}        ; (ldr r1, [sp], #4)
   0x796ac: mov r2, sp
   0x796b0: push    {r2}        ; (str r2, [sp, #-4]!)
   0x796b4: push    {r0}        ; (str r0, [sp, #-4]!)
   0x796b8: ldr r12, [pc, #16]  ; 0x796d0
   0x796bc: push    {r12}       ; (str r12, [sp, #-4]!)
   0x796c0: ldr r0, [pc, #12]   ; 0x796d4
   0x796c4: ldr r3, [pc, #12]   ; 0x796d8
   0x796c8: bl  0x4021a0
   0x796cc: bl  0x401fa0
   0x796d0: andeq   r2, r12, #200, 2    ; 0x32
   0x796d4: andeq   r10, r1, r12, lsl #11
   0x796d8: andeq   r2, r12, #40, 2
   0x796dc: ldr r3, [pc, #20]   ; 0x796f8
   0x796e0: ldr r2, [pc, #20]   ; 0x796fc
   0x796e4: add r3, pc, r3
   0x796e8: ldr r2, [r3, r2]
   0x796ec: cmp r2, #0
gef>
```

It all looks like valid ARM instructions.

In case it's relevant - All ldr instructions (0x796b8, 0x796c0, 0x796c4) in gdb are giving this message when executed: `Cannot access memory at address 0x0`. Some mov instructions throw this too.

At `0x796c8: bl  0x4021a0`:

```
->   0x796c8                  bl     0x4021a0
   \->    0x4021a0                  ldr    pc,  [pc,  #-4]  ; 0x4021a4
```

And eventually we get here:

```
gef> x/20i $pc
=> 0x20c1b30:   push    {r4, r5, r6, r7, lr}
   0x20c1b34:   sub sp, sp, #300    ; 0x12c
   0x20c1b38:   movw    r12, #0                 
   0x20c1b3c:   mov r5, r3                          --> Here is our illegal instruction
   0x20c1b40:   movt    r12, #0
   0x20c1b44:   str r1, [sp, #4]
   0x20c1b48:   movw    r1, #65336  ; 0xff38
   0x20c1b4c:   cmp r12, #0
   0x20c1b50:   ldr r3, [sp, #4]
   0x20c1b54:   str r2, [sp, #8]
   0x20c1b58:   ldrne   r12, [r12]
   0x20c1b5c:   add r2, r3, #1
   0x20c1b60:   str r0, [sp, #12]
   0x20c1b64:   movw    r3, #56376  ; 0xdc38
   0x20c1b68:   ldr r7, [sp, #8]
   0x20c1b6c:   movw    r0, #3092   ; 0xc14
   0x20c1b70:   ldr lr, [sp, #328]  ; 0x148
   0x20c1b74:   clzne   r12, r12
   0x20c1b78:   movt    r0, #685    ; 0x2ad
   0x20c1b7c:   movt    r1, #827    ; 0x33b
```

And of course a copy of the binary can be found here: https://mega.nz/#!CKxBQKaI!T__d9pjpOn_rPtfvPNkkPsFWHTjg7u-vDt5AK6610ug

So are the registers just not initialized to the right values? How can that be possible?

To paraphrase from Archer: What am I not getting?... I think the core concept.

I am probably missing a critical idea here. I'm hoping someone can help fill in the blank(s).

**UPDATE 1:**

At @0xC0000022L suggestion I looked into making sure the ARM revision of my VM/Pi matches that of the binary. As far as I can tell they do. Just comparing a binary from the VM to my my ARM binary I'm trying to get running their ABIs match (32-bit ARMv5):

```
$ file my_arm_bin 
my_arm_bin: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, ARM, EABI5 version 1 (SYSV), statically linked, for GNU/Linux 2.6.16, stripped
 $ file /usr/bin/id
/usr/bin/id: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, ARM, EABI5 version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3, for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, stripped
```

**UPDATE 2:**

At @perror suggestion I tried forcing the binary to execute in thumb mode. For context here is the disassembly when running in "arm" (non-thumb) mode:

```
gef> x/10i $pc
=> 0x20c1b38:   movw    r12, #0
   0x20c1b3c:   mov r5, r3
   0x20c1b40:   movt    r12, #0
   0x20c1b44:   str r1, [sp, #4]
   0x20c1b48:   movw    r1, #65336  ; 0xff38
   0x20c1b4c:   cmp r12, #0
   0x20c1b50:   ldr r3, [sp, #4]
   0x20c1b54:   str r2, [sp, #8]
   0x20c1b58:   ldrne   r12, [r12]
   0x20c1b5c:   add r2, r3, #1
```

Forcing thumb mode, I now see:

```
gef> set arm force-mode thumb
gef> x/10i $pc
=> 0x20c1b38:   stmia   r0!, {}
   0x20c1b3a:   b.n 0x20c213e
   0x20c1b3c:   str r3, [r0, r0]
   0x20c1b3e:   b.n 0x20c1e82
   0x20c1b40:   stmia   r0!, {}
   0x20c1b42:   b.n 0x20c21c6
   0x20c1b44:   asrs    r4, r0, #32
   0x20c1b46:   b.n 0x20c1664
   0x20c1b48:   subs    r0, r7, #4
   0x20c1b4a:   b.n 0x20c216c
```

Forcing thumb mode prior to execution, the program exits immediately with the following error:

```
[!] Cannot disassemble from $PC
[!] Cannot access memory at address 0x6ac
```

Starting the executable up, breaking and switching modes exits with an Illegal instruction error.

Comment: Just some random though I had while reading your post. Have you tried to check if you were in thumb mode ? Your disassembly is done in 32-bit mode, which is most likely assumed by `gdb`. But, what if the CPU was executing in thumb mode ? To check, you might also simply execute the program through `si` (`stepi`) commands until crash. It might give you a more insightful error message.

Comment: Another thing that comes to mind is the fact that your CPU may be of a different revision than the ARM code you're attempting to execute. Think ARMv5 vs. ARMv7 ...

Comment: Your description of what you're doing is unclear. Where does the error show? On what assembly line? What commands exactly do you execute to get from one snippet to the next?

Comment: @NirIzr The error I'm seeing is what is shown right after "Here is what I'm seeing:". In the part where I'm debugging with gdb, I'm using `ni` to step through instructions.

Thank you @perror and  @0xC0000022L - Your insight is much appreciated. I'm going to dig into thumb mode and ARM revision later today and will post and update. I was using `ni` to skip function calls and keep it simple, but `si` may give me some more context.

Comment: Would you mind including that as part of the question?

Comment: I've updated the part about gdb to mention that I was using `ni` to single step, and separated my problem statement for clarity

Comment: awesome this helped me to understand why my bitcoind crashed on my older raspi with "Illegal ins..." - armv6l only.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From a preliminary analysis the binary looks to be of atleast ARMv7. It runs under qemu-user without problems.

```
$ qemu-arm --version
qemu-arm version 2.11.0
Copyright (c) 2003-2017 Fabrice Bellard and the QEMU Project developers

$ qemu-arm ./my_arm_bin 
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
Name:storage
Version:1.05.3
Build date:Apr 24 2018 13:16:31
Desc:DriverManager release
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
Name:manager
Version:1.03.1
Build date:Apr 24 2018 13:16:31
Desc:
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
Name:manager
Version:1.03.1
Build date:Apr 24 2018 13:16:31
Desc:
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
Name:guictrls
Version:1.05.5
Build date:Apr 24 2018 13:16:31
Desc:GUI ctrls Relese
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
Name:OS
Version:1.00.1
Build date:Apr 24 2018 13:16:31
Desc:OS Relese
------snip-------------------
```

However, running under a ARMv6 QEMU VM it crashes with an Illegal instruction, similar to yours. Digging deep there're indeed some instructions which are invalid under ARMv5.

```
─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────[ code:arm ]────
    0x20c1b2c                  bl     0x20d434c
    0x20c1b30                  push   {r4,  r5,  r6,  r7,  lr}
    0x20c1b34                  sub    sp,  sp,  #300    ; 0x12c
 →  0x20c1b38                  movw   r12,  #0
    0x20c1b3c                  mov    r5,  r3
    0x20c1b40                  movt   r12,  #0
    0x20c1b44                  str    r1,  [sp,  #4]
    0x20c1b48                  movw   r1,  #65336   ; 0xff38
    0x20c1b4c                  cmp    r12,  #0
──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────[ threads ]────
[#0] Id 1, Name: "my_arm.bin", stopped, reason: SIGILL
────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────[ trace ]────
[#0] 0x20c1b38 → movw r12,  #0
[#1] 0x796cc → bl 0x401fa0
```

Above it crashed on the `movw   r12,  #0` at `0x20c1b38`. Now the `movw` was introduced in ARMv7 and unavailable in ARMv5. Similarly the `movt` instruction is also invalid under v5.

[image]

**[Image Source](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dai0425/BABHFAFI.html)**

This explains why ARM v5/v6 qemu is crashing. So to run the binary you would atleast need an ARMv7 QEMU vm or the Raspberry Pi 2 which sports an ARMv7 processor.

Comment: You sir are my hero. I was using `file` to tell me which version of ARM the file uses, which is incorrect. For anyone that runs across this in the future: use `readelf -A my_arm_bin` instead, specifically check the `Tag_CPU_arch` flag output. In this case it is `v7`.

Comment: Thankyou so much, I was in exactly the same situation as you - I even downloaded the same versatilepb image. `Tag_CPU_name: "CORTEX-A8"` `Tag_CPU_arch: v7` - time to go find a `v7` QEMU image.....